# PowerShell error in renaming of subfolders

Tags: powershell, rename, subdirectory

I am a PowerShell newbie. I have the following command to rename all subfolders:

```
Get-ChildItem -r | foreach{Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace "2021", "2021 renamed")}
```

This command works correctly, but also returns an error message:

```
Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:28
+ ... e | foreach{Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace "2021", "2021 r ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\abc\...def\ghi\2025:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Where `...def\ghi\2025` is the last subfolder.

Could someone please advise me what the error in my command is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only rename subfolders, then you should add `-Directory` parameter. Also, you can pipe directly to `Rename-Item`, no foreach loop is required. The error message is shown for those items that you don't actually change (don't have 2021 in the name for example so the new name is the same as the old.) You could just set erroraction to silently continue.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "2021", "2021 renamed"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Or if you'd prefer you can stick with the loop and only attempt to rename those that actually have the matching criteria

```
Get-ChildItem -r | ForEach-Object{
    if($_.name -match '2021')
    {
        Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace "2021", "2021 renamed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Doug Maurer - clearly explained, so now I can stop chasing my tail!

Comment: There is a gotcha with iterating files/folders and renaming them in the pipeline straight away though.. `Get-ChildItem` may pick up items that have already been renamed, and to overcome that you should let Get-ChildItem finish before piping to Rename-Item by surrounding it with brackets: `(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse) | Rename-Item ..` Also, why not use `-Filter '*2021*'` to get only folders that have 2021 in their name?